# BeanCreationException with nested exception of StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mybatis, weblogic11g

I've got a large web application (running on *weblogic* 11g) that uses a combination of *spring*, *spring-security*, *mybatis* and *mybatis-spring*.  It uses mybatis:scan with a marker-interface (`DataAccess`) to wire the `SqlSessionFactory` into our *DAOs*.  We have 61 classes (interfaces) that extend the marker interface.

When we add one more interface that extends `DataAccess` (the marker) the application fails to start.  I'd like to know if anyone can help figure out why adding one more `DataAccess` causes the application to get these errors.

I can provide any information that will help figure this out but I didn't know what to include in my initial question.

Here are the first two errors in the *log4j* log file:

> 2014-Jul-14 12:58:22.659 [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '40' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
>   Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'paymentsDataAccess' defined in file
>   [/opt/..../tmp/_WL_user/..../an9ko4/APP-INF/classes/com/..../payment/app/dao/PaymentsDataAccess.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property
>   'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name
>   'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource
>   [ServiceConfig.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [ServiceConfig.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> 2014-Jul-14 12:58:22.666 [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '40' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
>   Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'adminSessionDataAccess' defined in file
>   [/opt/..../tmp/_WL_user/..../an9ko4/APP-INF/classes/com/..../dao/AdminSessionDataAccess.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property
>   'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name
>   'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource
>   [ServiceConfig.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [ServiceConfig.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
>   class org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean

The first error has the nested exception of a `StackOverflowError` and when I've looked at a generated stack trace the call stack is over 1000 methods deep.  I can provide the stack trace if asked but it's so big I didn't want to include it unless there is interest.

The `PaymentsDataAccess` class isn't special in any way - it's just like the other data access classes in the application.

When the application doesn't start there also seems to be another error (in *server.log*) but I'm not sure if it's related:

> java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at
>   ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 805

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Yes, but the initialization is just fine when there is one fewer DataAccess bean.  Also, there isn't any indication why the initialization failed unless it's the instrument failure.

Answer (score 0):

What's your mybatis-spring version.If your version is lower than 1.2.0, it indeed causes stackoverflow error. And try 1.2.3.